# Use repeater field in Wordpress menu-walker

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the walker menu function to create a submenu for each menu-item.
I'm using a repeater field to create info-divs and for each `the_sub_field('info_block_img_file')` on the current page I want to output a new `li` in the menu. But I don't now how implement it correctly in the walker.
This is what I tried, and it obviously didn't work:

```
    var $tree_type = array( 'post_type', 'taxonomy', 'custom' );

    var $db_fields = array( 'parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 'id' => 'db_id' );

    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-menu\">\n";
    }
    function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
    }

    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

        $atts = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
        $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
        $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';


        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args );

        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';

        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= $args->after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';


        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );

        //Here’s where I’m trying to put my submenu:

        $output .= '<ul id="about" class="dropDown">'. if(get_field('info_block')):
                while(has_sub_field('info_block')): .'
        <li><a href="#">'. get_sub_field('info_block_header') .'</a></li>'. endwhile; endif; .
        </ul>'; 

    }   function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $output .= "</li>\n";
    }

} // Walker_Nav_Menu
?>
```

Comment: are you getting any error ? it seems you have syntax error near `endwhile; endif; .`

Comment: What I get is: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF

Comment: i have corrected your code and added the output you want i don't know what you are getting in `has_sub_field('info_block')`. hope it full fill your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Custom_walker_class extends Walker {

  var $db_fields = array( 'parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 'id' => 'db_id' );

  function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul>\n";
  }

  function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
  }

  function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {

    global $wp_query;
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
    $class_names = $value = '';
    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

    /* Add active class */
    if(in_array('current-menu-item', $classes)) {
      $classes[] = 'active';
      unset($classes['current-menu-item']);
    }

    /* Check for children */
    $children = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'nav_menu_item', 'nopaging' => true, 'numberposts' => 1, 'meta_key' => '_menu_item_menu_item_parent', 'meta_value' => $item->ID));
    if (!empty($children)) {
      $classes[] = 'has-sub';
    }

    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
    $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

    $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
    $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

    $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'><span>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</span></a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    // you need to call your custom out before applying filter
    $output .= '<ul id="about" class="dropDown">';

            if (get_field('info_block')):

                 while (has_sub_field('info_block')): ;

               $output .='<li><a href="#">' . get_sub_field('info_block_header') . '</a></li>';

                endwhile; 
            endif;

      $output .= '</ul>';

    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
  }

  function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $output .= "</li>\n";
  }
}
```

1. You had syntax error near `'. endwhile; endif; .` you forget to use 
   single quote `'` after concatinate the variable .
2. You need to call your custom **output** before `applying_filter` function because this will return output just after calling this
   function.

Comment: Cool thanks.
The only problem now is that the dropdown comes before the <a> tag of the parent <li>... but I think I can move around some stuff to get it fixed.

Comment: I seriously spent like 3 hours googling a solution for this, and could not find anything!

Comment: do you know how can output the `walker` after the `<a>`-link of each `menu-item`?

Solved it! (by moving the `apply_filters` above my custom stuff

Comment: I cant understand you? do you want to display dropdown menu right after `<a>` ?

Comment: Exactly, sorry if I was unclear, but I found the quite easy solution to that :)

Comment: I am glad if you found another solution too. best of luck :)